# Extract date with varying length from text string

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2019

When my data in `field1` is formatted consistently as mm/dd/yy, I can extract the date using this:

`substring([field1],patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%',[field1]),8)`

However, sometimes it comes in with only one digit for the day and/or month (if less than 10).

I thought I would be able to catch that by using `patindex('%[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+%',[field1])`, since `+` should match one or more occurrences (and also tried with the + inside the brackets `[0-9+]`) but those don't match the pattern.

Is there another method that works?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex. The real question is why are you storing a date in a `varchar` in the first place? It's because that that design that you're having the problem. Why not fix the design and put the date in a `date` column?

Comment: At the very least you need to post some sample data and table structures. What you need to do here is ugly for sure and highly error prone. But without something to work with nobody can help.

Comment: just try the three different patindex variations to catch the various encodings

Comment: If your data is in inconsistent format like m/d/y and mm/dd/y then couldn't it also be coming in d/m/y? Also does your data really use two-digit years!?!? It's like we're not learning any computer science lessons for three decades!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Honestly, the **best** way to handle this (by far!) is to have a preprocessing layer in a traditional language to clean up the data _before_ loading to SQL Server. Don't ever let string dates get to the database in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is awful and deserves better care of your data. As [Joel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963920/extract-date-with-varying-length-from-text-string/76964460#comment135677730_76963920), preferably, before it *ever* gets anywhere near the database. You shouldn't be storing dates as strings, or as parts of strings - if this is important data, it should be stored separately, using the correct data type. And it shouldn't be coming into the system in inconsistent, cowboy formats; maybe sometimes we like two digits and maybe sometimes we don't, and with 2-digit years no less. Data modelers everywhere are crying.

Anywho, since the response is likely going to be "it's not my system, I didn't design it, and I can't change it" - and since SQL Server doesn't support proper RegEx - here's how I would deal with it.

Create a table with all of your potential formats, the length they might be, and the style you want to convert (`1`/`101` for `m/d/y`, `3`/`103` for `d/m/y`). If it could be either, stop now and go back to the first paragraph because you're hosed. If you don't know if `7/8/23` is July 8 or August 7, no amount of RegEx is going to save you anyway.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DateFormats
(
  pattern  varchar(100),
  len      tinyint,
  style    tinyint,
  ordering tinyint
);

INSERT dbo.DateFormats VALUES
('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 10, 101, 1),
('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',       9, 101, 2),
('[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',       9, 101, 3),
('[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',            8, 101, 4),
('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]',            8, 1,   5),
('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]',                 7, 1,   6),
('[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]',                 7, 1,   7),
('[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]',                      6, 1,   8);
```

Now, consider that you have a table with a bunch of garbage:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.trash
(
  column1 varchar(255)
);

INSERT dbo.trash(column1) VALUES
('some garbage here 01/03/2022 eh?'),
('wow some garbage here too 1/03/2022|huh?'),
('and garbage here also 01/3/22\yeah!'),
('and also 1/3/2022 yeah-huh and a second one 1/4/2055!'),
('2/2/22===and what if it starts that way?'),
('12/3/22');
```

Then we can just use cross apply to find the date string that matches one of the patterns, we process them in a specific order so `12/12/2022` doesn't match `m/dd/yyyy` first, for example. And we pad each side of the source column in case the value starts or ends with a date, and we pad the pattern with anything that's not a number so we don't find the wrong thing.

```
SELECT t.column1, 
  ParsedDate = TRY_CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING(t.column1, p.pos, p.len), p.style)
FROM dbo.trash AS t
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) pos = PATINDEX('%' + pattern + '%', t.column1), len, style
   FROM dbo.DateFormats 
   WHERE 'x' + t.column1 + 'x' LIKE '%[^0-9]' + pattern + '[^0-9]%'
   ORDER BY ordering
) AS p;
```

Results:

| column1 | ParsedDate |
| --- | --- |
| some garbage here 01/03/2022 eh? | 2022-01-03 |
| wow some garbage here too 1/03/2022|huh? | 2022-01-03 |
| and garbage here also 01/3/22\yeah! | 2022-01-03 |
| and also 1/3/2022 yeah-huh and a second one 1/4/2055! | 2022-01-03 |
| 2/2/22===and what if it starts that way? | 2022-02-02 |
| 12/3/22 | 2022-12-03 |

- [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j0NuIgJ-)

Caveats:

- Again, if you have a mix of `m/d/y` and `d/m/y`, it's over.
- This solution will only identify the *first* date matching one of the specified formats.
- Change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY` if you want to include source rows that don't contain a date in any format.

Comment: the short answer (besides changing the way data comes in) seems to be that it can't be done programatically so all the scenarios need to be handled explicitly. this is a very efficient way to do it